# Create gem package from installed gem

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems

I've got a bunch of installed ruby gems on one PC and want to copy them to another PC that has no internet connection. Is that possible to pack installed gems back to *.gem files and then use "gem install %path_to_local_gem%" command to install them?

Comment: that's exatcly what i'm looking for, thanx! but it isn't works for a few packs, sass for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bundler. You may install your application gems in a machine with no internet connection by issuing:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

For that you have to have installed bundler in the first place, of course. Maybe you can even find it in your OS's package system.